# I can't get any response from client via socket

Tags: python, sockets

```
#Server

import socket

HOST = # Server IP
PORT = # Server Port

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(f"[+] Connected by {addr}")

    while True:
        command = input(">> ")
        conn.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
        result = b""
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            result += data
        print(result.decode())
```

```
# Client
import socket
import subprocess

HOST = # Server IP
PORT = # Server Port

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    while True:
        command = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        result = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        chunk_size = 4096
        for i in range(0, len(result), chunk_size):
            s.send(result[i:i + chunk_size].encode('utf-8'))
```

I tried to send result of command entered in server by chunks but can't get any result after doing it. Before adding for loop (to send result by chunks) in the client code I was able to get result of command sent by server but I want to get large results at once couldn't find any way to achieve this.

Comment: There are several problems here. The main problem is that you expect `recv` to return nothing if the "message" is done. But TCP is a byte stream and has no concept of a message. Instead it will block until it gets more data or the TCP connection was closed by the peer. Apart from that you wrongly assume that `send` sends everything (use `sendall` for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to send the length of the data before sending the data itself. This way, the receiver knows how much data to expect.

Server.py:

```
import socket

HOST = "your_server_ip"
PORT = your_server_port

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(f"[+] Connected by {addr}")

    while True:
        command = input(">> ")
        conn.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
        result = conn.recv(1024)  # Receive the data size first
        data_size = int(result.decode())
        result = b""
        while len(result) < data_size:
            data = conn.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            result += data
        print(result.decode())
```

Client.py:

```
import socket
import subprocess

HOST = "your_server_ip"
PORT = your_server_port

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    while True:
        command = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        result = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        result_size = str(len(result)).encode('utf-8')
        s.send(result_size)  # Send the size of the data first
        chunk_size = 4096
        for i in range(0, len(result), chunk_size):
            s.send(result[i:i + chunk_size].encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware: you must give the server a chance to identify the end of a series of chunks. Currently you are looping until you get a EOF, which only occurs after a `close` or `shutdown` on the peer. But after that, the connection cannot be re-used.

So a possible way would be to use a brand new connection per command.

Server could become:

```
...
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(f"[+] Connected by {addr}")
        ...
```

and client:

```
...
while True:
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        command = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        result = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        chunk_size = 4096
        for i in range(0, len(result), chunk_size):
            s.send(result[i:i + chunk_size].encode('utf-8'))
```